# How can i show a particular column to list view in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to show setName column as a list view how it is possible in android.
I am share my code.

```
private String lv_arr[];
String selectList = "select setName from Displaysettings";      
DBConnect conn1 = new DBConnect(getApplicationContext(), "colorCode");      
conn1.execNonQuery(selectList);
lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
String[] setNameValues = new String[] {
            "setName1",
            "setName2",
            "setName3"
    };

    // Create a simple array adapter (of type string) 
    //with the setName values returned by conn1.execNonquery
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, setNameValues);
```

So, you should convert your conn1.execNonQuery(selectList) result to a string array

Update:

Or you can use a cursor adapter, if your conn1.execNonQuery return a cursor.

For example (some lines are delete to make it clear)

```
public class DiagramListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private boolean dataValid;
    private boolean autoRequery;
    private boolean autoRequeryInProgress;
    private int count = -1;

    public DiagramListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autorequery) {
        super(context, c, autorequery);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(final Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.diagram_item, null);
        DiagramListCursorWrapper wrapper;
        wrapper = new DiagramListCursorWrapper(v);
        v.setTag(wrapper);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        DiagramListCursorWrapper wrapper = (DiagramListCursorWrapper) v.getTag();
        wrapper.populateFrom(cursor);
    }

    void refresh() {
        if (getCursor() != null) {
            getCursor().requery();
        }
    }


    public class DiagramListCursorWrapper {
        TextView title;

        public DiagramListCursorWrapper(View v) {
            setupViews(v, null);
        }

        public DiagramListCursorWrapper(View v, Context context) {
            setupViews(v, context);
        }

        private void setupViews(View v, Context context) {
            title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        }

        public void populateFrom(Cursor cursor) {
            if (cursor != null) {
                try {
                    title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DiagramsADO.DIAGRAM_TITLE)));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: but i dont want to use hard coded. it will come from android database.

Comment: i only show you an example, you should adapt it to your needs, besides, we dont know your cursor structure to offer a better idea, but you can loop your cursor and build a dinamic string array, or as i said a cursor Adapter is better dedendin on conn1.execNonQuery result type

Comment: String selectList = "select setName from Displaysettings";  
  DBConnect conn1 = new DBConnect(getApplicationContext(), "colorCode"); 
  
  Cursor cur1 = conn1.execNonQuery(selectList);
   
    for (int i=0; i<cur1.getColumnCount(); i++) {
      
     lv_arr[i] = cur1.getString(i);
     System.out.println(lv_arr);
    
     }

Comment: rigth! or you can adapt the cursor adapter sample to work direcly with your cur1

Comment: but my dear friend its gives me error about database. force close are there.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to fetch all the results into the Cursor and then use to cursor and add the contents to ListView

Comment: ok so can you give me hint about how to take cursor and store result into that?

Comment: you need to do a cursor adapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html